# setIcon with switch

Tags: java, image, swing, switch-statement, icons

I have a little question.
I have made a java switch in Netbeans. The switch is attached to a label in my Gui. Whenever i click the Label, i want it to be able to change the image it has.

```
private void LoopLblMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
switch(looped)
{
    case 0:
        looped = 1;
        LoopLbl.setIcon("path to image");
        break;

    case 1:
        looped = 0;
        break;
};
```

This the code i have for the switch untill now, but it gives an error when i fill in the path to the image. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is your "error". Shot in the dark guess is you're not escaping your backspaces. Complete shot in the dark though.

Comment: Let me guess: your path to the image contains a backslash, and you forgot to escape it with another backslash, right?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)? The parameter to setIcon is of type `Icon`, not `String`.

Answer (score 2):

> but it gives an error when i fill in the path to the image.

```
LoopLbl.setIcon("path to image");
```

Did you read the API? The `setIcon()` takes an `Icon` as a parameter, not a `String`.

If you want to know how to use Icons, read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples.

I suggest you keep the tutorial link handy for learning the basics of Swing.